# How to get a combo in Disco Dave?

Tags: ios, disco-dave

I recently downloaded a game for my iPhone called Disco Dave, it has a combo system in it to allow you to get more points in the game, however, there doesn't appear to be any clear pattern to the combos and they seem mostly random.

So I was wondering how do you get a combo, and is there a pattern to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that with a combo you mean a score multiplier? If so then this will help you out:

"Bounce on the tile that has the same color as the square surrounding the dance floor. As you keep matching colors, your multiplier will increase by one and that multiplier will then increase the number of points you've earned through the combo. That means jumping on five tiles in a row while matching colors will earn you 25 points, six color-matched tiles in a row 36 and so on and so forth" [Source](http://www.levelwinner.com/disco-dave-tips-tricks-cheats-dance-way-higher-score/). *Be warned though: This came from a tips and tricks post, so possibly not everything that is on there is what you want to read*